# How to set specific columns values automatically from database in javafx tableview?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, desktop

This is my table with some columns. I need to set some columns values automatically from the database but some needs to be blank for manual entry. And after that editing, I have to read whole table view and store into database.
[image: Tableview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pratik,

What you want to do is never mind about the Table right now and just think about moving the data out of the database and into a data structure. How would you accomplish that task?

Then pretend the data in the data strcuture has changed. Now you want to move the data  out of that  data structure and back into the database, updating the database.

Once you have that working, then consider your Table. Your goal will be to take the data in the data structure and use it to create a Table.

Then the last thing left to do is use the data in the Table and  populate your data structure with it.

If you can do those things, then you will have a solution to every step of your problem.

The easiest data structure to use is an `ObservableArrayList`. You can directly populate a TableView with an instance of ObservableArrayList using the TableView's `setItems(observableArrayList)` method.

Comment: hello, I successfully done these tasks and got my solution. _Thank You._